# Can we call something a "word" if it doesn't have a vowel?

Tags: meaning, nouns, orthography, vowels

It seems self-evident to me, but in the heat of a Scrabble game (no surprise), my opponent claimed that "sh" was a word. I think it's a diphthong, but the printed dictionary definition of "word" didn't resolve the issue.

I know that Scrabble-related questions on this site are generally regarded as *infra dig*, but the event really did cause me to wonder what truly qualifies as a "word" and what doesn't.

[I also understand that this question sits just atop the divide between meaning and orthography, but hey, whtvr.]

Comment: You could look up [sh](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sh?s=t) instead. Looks legit to me.

Comment: [sh](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/shh)! [mmm](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mmm), [hmm](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hmm)?

Comment: No one can give a ruling as to if something is a *word*, in absolute terms. Depending on context, those strings of characters listed in 'the lexicon' (standard dictionaries?) may be considered *words* for general English usage purposes. Scrabble, on the other hand, has its own set of standard references for what it considers legitimate words.

Comment: What made you think something is not a word "if it doesn't have a vowel?" any references? Is *whtvr* a word, or not a word?

Comment: Incidentally, the two-letter words acceptable in Scrabble is well-defined and worth being familiar with if you play. They'll win games by allowing placement better than knowing lots of larger words.

Comment: Also, not a diphthong.

Comment: What is the second letter of the English alphabet? What letter often represents a percentage score of 80-89? What's the first letter of the words 'bee'? The word 'B' may not be acceptable in Scrabble, but it's definitely a word. 'nth' is probably the most commonly used example of a vowel-less word

Comment: A letter isn't a word any more than a tire is a car.

Comment: @Jeff: "Also, not a diphthong." Yes, I was wrong there. Sorry.

Comment: if it's in OSPD (or SOWPODS) then it's a word.

Answer (score 18):

*Sh* has entries in the Oxford English Dictionary as a verb, a noun and an interjection. The letters S and H do not constitute a diphthong. Rather, they represent the consonant /ʃ/.

*Word* is difficult to define satisfactorily, but it is determined as much by its syntactical function as by its form and meaning. The definition in ‘The Cambridge Encyclopedia of the English Language’ is as good as any:

> The smallest unit of grammar that can stand alone as a complete
>   utterance, separated by spaces in written language and potentially by
>   pauses in speech.

These conditions can be satisfied even when a word is not in any dictionary.

Comment: Plus, Scrabble is a game, with its own rules and definitions. Generalized dictionary definitions are always trumpable by specialized local idiomatic uses and definitions. Rules can be changed locally, of course; but it's the game rules that count, not the dictionary.

Comment: [Take 2] Thanks, Barry, I think the "smallest unit ... that serves a syntactical function" is the most serviceable definition I'll end up finding here. I was originally looking for guidance that superseded Scrabble (I regret using the game as a metonym -the rules of that croft are irrelevant to my question), Czech, Cymric, onamatopoeia, "look it up, fool" answers, and whtvr the web dishes up. Thanks, all.

Answer (score 3):

As general, there are words without vowels, but with consonants functioning as a vovel, such as r in famous Czech sentence: [Strč prst skrz krk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Str%C4%8D_prst_skrz_krk)

Because human languages tend to copy from each other, it is possible that such words would be sooner or later imported into English.

Many pronouns in many languages are single-letter words (such as w, z in Polish).

So we can definitely call something a word if it has no vowels. It would be possible to define something as "English word" stating that because there's no word in English that has vowels we can state that word must have at least one vowel, but it would be too artificial.

"Sh" could be classified as exclamation or onomatopoeia, so it's up to scrabble rules to define if such words are legal or not. Accepting one-letter words in Polish, for example, would make no sense for scrabble although they are fully legal words.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a word without a vowel: **cwn**

Source: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/c%C5%B5n

Also see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_words_without_vowels

Comment: In Welsh words like cwn and cwm, I would argue that w is a vowel.

Comment: When I was in school, we were taught that the vowels are a, e, i, o, u and "sometimes y and w".

Comment: And sometimes u is consonant

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, I would say "YES!" As far as "sh" is concerned, the dictionary says it is an interjection used to urge silence. An interjection is a word or phrase expressive of emotion. So it is a word by that definition.

Another example is the word, "By". It is a two letter word without a vowel.
[Definition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/by?s=t)

[Here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/word?s=t) is the Dictionary.com definition of "word".

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of english words that have no vowels: `rhythm`, `crypt` and `flyby` to name a few. In the vast majority of cases, the `y` acts as a vowel. The exceptions are usually interjections: `hmm`, `hmph`, `psst`

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_words_in_English_without_A,_E,_I,_O_or_U

Comment: Well, I think "y" would be called a vowel in your first three examples, so the words do have a vowel.